# flutter said module 'firebase_auth' not found

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase

I was made a new flutter project in android studio macbook air M1.

1. Add "firebase_auth: ^4.6.1" in pubspec.yaml.
2. Pub get click and debug start.
3. The error occured.

Here is my spec.

```
Macbook air M1 ventura 13.4
cocoapods 1.12.1
Xcode 14.3
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.10, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale ko-KR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I tried:

Remove `{app_test}/ios/Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods/`

In terminal,

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod init (in ios folder)
pod intall
```

also run `pod intall --repo-update` and etc.
I trid what i can, but it always said module 'firebase_auth' not found.
But another package works well. (ex. provider or ..)

I hope it says "Build Success!"

What should I do?
I feel like I'm going crazy.
I'm losing my hair because of this.

Comment: Have you found a solution?